# Jitsi multiple streams handling

Tags: stream, video-streaming, jitsi

I have a Jitsi instance that I would like to share with 50 people for an event. I will mute everyone to make sure that only one or two people are talking at the same time but I wonder if I need to ask people to cut the video too (which would be sad because seeing other people face would be fun).

I know that Jitsi works in peer to peer when only two people are connected but what about a larger room?

Does the server centralise all the video stream?

Answer (score 0):

With more than two participants [Jitsi Videobridge](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge) will take over (no peer to peer nor H264) and control video streams from clients to server to clients.

As far as I understand it works very much like a turn server.

It strongly depends on your hardware setup. If *Jitsi* is running on a dedicated machine it should be able to handle this.

On a virtual server on the other hand...

Comment: What do you mean by *a turn server* ?

Comment: https://github.com/coturn/coturn  a very good open source TURN server

Comment: @exceptionvalueerror is right that the bridge handles calls with > 2 participants.  You can also configure `startAudioMuted` and `startVideoMuted` to a low number: when participants after that amount join they are audio/video muted by default.  50 participants is a lot, but with most video and audio muted it should be fine on a sufficiently-sized bridge (~c5.xlarge).  Also, you can always use meet.jit.si for your meeting :)

Comment: @exceptionvalueerror How coturn is related to jitsi?